# Angularjs : track by multiple select same object

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've a problem with a multiple select. I want to show tags by category but there is a something specific : **a tag can may belong to one or more categories**.

My problem is for a tag which is in two differents categories. How deal with this ?

Here what I have for now :

```html
// vm.tagCategories
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"category 1",
    "description":"category 1",
    "tags":
      [
        {"id":1,
        "name":"tag 1",
        "description":"test"
      }
      ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"category 2",
    "description":"category 2",
    "tags":
      [
        {
          "id":1,
          "name":"tag 1",
          "description":"test"
        },
        {
          "id":2,
          "name":"tag 2",
          "description":"test 2"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

```html
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Tags</label>

        <md-select ng-model="vm.selectedTags" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" multiple>
            <md-optgroup label="{{currentCategories.name}}" ng-repeat="currentCategories in vm.tagCategories">
                <md-option ng-value="{{value}}" ng-repeat="(key, tag) in currentCategories">{{tag.name}}</md-option>
            </md-optgroup>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

[image]

When I check tag 2 in category 1, it's tag 2 in category 2 which is checked but not the first one. (If I check the "tag 2", this is what I have) :

[image]

[The plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/536W0bfzp3Rax2Hmnn0j)

Comment: It's exactly doing what you ask: 'Track the items by id, all the items with the same id are the same items'

Comment: My bad... I didn't finish my last sentence. I edited my question

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this behavior in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue), to help us to resolve your problem.

Comment: I edited my question with the problem on plunker

Answer (score 0):

The option `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"` is used to change the way that **Javascript** check the equality between your model `selectedTags` and the different items of your select. With this, instead of checking if they are the same objects in memory, it compares if they get the same `id`. But two of your items have the same id so only one is checked (I don't know why only the second one is checked and not the first one or both).

So you just need to remove it :

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedTags" placeholder="Select an Option" multiple>
    <md-optgroup label="{{item.name}}" ng-repeat="item in tagCategories">
        <md-option ng-value="value" ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.tags">{{value.name}}</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zah7gAM7YDi6mf9TBgmv?p=preview) is your plunker corrected.

Comment: ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" is used to init the list and check the tags already selected (from database). Try it with selectedTags array commented in app.js. Maybe there is another way to check the tags (selected=true) already selected in database

Comment: Yes but if I understand well the doc,  using this will makes Javascript compare the id of your elements (to know if they are checked or not), but two of your items have the same id so one of them will never be checked.

Comment: So instead of using this, to make an item selected by default make directly reference to it in your controller. Like this : `$scope.selectedTags = [$scope.tagCategories[0].tags[0]]`

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I'm going to create an unique id for each option with category.id and tag.id. (PS : I didn't see your last comment)

Comment: If my answer solve your problem if you could accept it, it would be great. Or if you found another solution to your problem do not hesitate to answer to your own question (to close the question)

Comment: Finally, I solved my problem but not like this because... it was impossible. I display only tags.